# Spring ServletContext bean (i.e. Controller) injection into ApplicationContext bean (i.e. Service, Dao)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

In Spring, relationship between Application Context and Servlet Context is like parent-child. Application Context is the parent here. So, beans of Servlet Context know beans of Application Context, but vise versa is not true. But if I need to do that, is there any way ?

For simplicity, if I inject an Controller into an Service class, what I need to do ? Is there any Application Context refreshing mechanism, after Servlet Context is initialized ?

Comment: The  Application Context and Servlet Context are totally 2 differenct conceptions, there is nothing comparable. it make sence if you mean WebApplicationContext and ApplicationContext is like parent-child.

Comment: You shouldn't injecte a controller in a service. That would ruin your layered architecture where each layer depends on the next one, and not vice-versa. If A must be injected into B, then B should be in the same context as A, or in a sub-context of A.

Comment: @JBNizet - I want to keep them in different context. Normally we don't inject a controller into a service class. I just need to know if there is any possible way to do that.